# Let class have unique id which doesn't ever change, no matter what

Tags: c#, enums, attributes, uid

I have classes that might or might not change their name (and members) during development. My classes are used (in most cases) like enums, but I couldn't use enums because I needed slightly more functionality. Since classes (obviously) don't have an Integer representing them under the surface I need to create some solution for having similar functionality. In other words, I want for each class to be represented by an Integer (or some other unique identifier).

I've created this attribute:

```
public class IdAttribute : Attribute
{
    private int id = -1;
    public IdAttribute(int index)
    {
        this.id = index;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using it as following:

```
[Id(0)]
public class Hello: Core { }
[Id(1)]
public class Bye: Core { }
```

As you can see it's quite error prone, since I don't want any class to have the same Id. And thus, optimally I want an automatic generated id, but I don't want it to change if I ever change anything regarding the class, for example the class name or its members.

What's the best way to achieve this?

(I know that in Java, that once you make a class Serializable, you'll get an automatically generated id (is there something like this in C#?).)

EDIT:
The reason I "couldn't" just use enums is because of (mainly) convenience. I have classes which exposes fields in an editor. And in this editor I can select only the appropriate "enums", in some cases only enums which inherits from "Core" will be displayed and in other cases they might inherit from "Tools" or some other class. I hope that cleared up a bit.

Comment: A quick solution would have each class store an enum and have a different enum for each class

Comment: I'm rather curious why you would want to do this?

Comment: *I couldn't use enums because I needed slightly more functionality*. Can you be more specific? Maybe we can solve that problem. Why is the ID important to you?

Comment: I also have some doubts you really need that, but if you do - you can use Guid instead of integer for id, and generate it from Visual Studio itself with VS marco\snippet. If you use Resharper, there is already such snippet - type "nguid" and press tab to create new guid.

Comment: A class already has such an id, you do not have to help.  Use typeof(foo).GUID.   The returned guid is stable as long as you don't change the class.

Comment: @HansPassant From post: *"but I don't want it to change if I ever change anything regarding the class"*

Comment: Write a unit-test to ensure you don't get duplicated ID's.

Comment: @HansPassant author wants it to be stable even if class _name_ changes.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, that's why I included it.  The convenience is hard to pass up, pragmatic programmers *do* sometimes change their requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you'd need to do this, but you could do the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class IdAttribute:Attribute
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public IdAttribute(string id)
    {
        Id = new Guid(id);
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like:

```
[IdAttribute("7d7952d1-86df-4e2e-b040-fed335aad775")]
public class SomeClass
{
   //example, you'd obviously cache this
   public Guid Id => GetType().GetCustomAttribute<IdAttribute>().Id;

   //...
}
```

Do note, that `Guid`s *are not* random. If you need a random id, then this isn't the solution. To generate a `Guid` read comments to your question.

Comment: I will consider this solution and see if I can write a VS macro (never done that) to create a GUID. Thank you!

Comment: @Whyser you can use many of the existing extensions for this purpose, like this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=autumn009.GuidInserter2

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that through your base class `Core`:

```
public abstract class Core
{
    public Core()
    {
        Type myType = this.GetType();
        object[] attrs = myType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IdAttribute), false);
        IdAttribute attr = attrs?.OfType<IdAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        int id = -1;
        if (attr != null) id = attr.Id;
        if (!reservedIdentities.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            reservedIdentities.Add(id, myType);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!reservedIdentities[id].Equals(myType))
                throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate identities discovered.", nameof(id));
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<int, Type> reservedIdentities = new Dictionary<int, Type>();

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this doesn't solve my problem, only help me find when I made a mistake.